# FilterXML Formula Comes Empty for some of Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a question, hopefully you may be able to help. I have been using MS Excel 2016 where i have number of data like in attached below file.

Where `FILTERXML` works for some cells and pulls the data but it also does not work for some cells which has similar data and returns empty.

I tried and clean the cell data while seeing to other cells data, which result is appearing with formula but it was not still working.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,B$1&":","<r/>"),CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[r]["&COUNTIF($B$1:B$1,B$1)&"]"),"")
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xv4BUh8sObhVirqYK2fsLfwsydvrs4rv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula uses `XML` filtering using `XPATH`. But for `XML` there are some characters having special meaning and must be escaped. For example your text `Pharmacy: 1ST AID PHARMACY & SURGICAL SUPPLIE` would must be `Pharmacy: 1ST AID PHARMACY &amp; SURGICAL SUPPLIE` in `XML`. This is because `&` marks the start of an entity in `XML` and needs to be escaped if it not has that meaning.

So you would must substtute all `&` with `&amp;`.

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"&","&amp;"),B$1&":","<r/>"),CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[r]["&COUNTIF($B$1:B$1,B$1)&"]"),"")
```

But there are multiple other such characters. Character `<` for example would must be `&lt;`. This is because `<` marks the start of a tag in `XML` and needs to be escaped if it not has that meaning.

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"<","&lt;"),"&","&amp;"),B$1&":","<r/>"),CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[r]["&COUNTIF($B$1:B$1,B$1)&"]"),"")
```

Maybe there are others too, so the `SUBSTITUTE` chain gets longer and longer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution i have been striving since yesterday to make it work according to requirements but when i stuck i just though that there is problem in the data. Thank once again for the Answer.